# Kendo ListView: Add/Create not reflected until browser session is refreshed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listview, kendo-ui, tempdata, transport

I'm using MVC and a Kendo (UI v2018.3.1017) ListView to manage a list I refer to as 'MaximoList'. To make the list available to multiple controllers, I'm leveraging the MVC provided "TempData" object. On Create (and Destroy), I see that the MaximoList object is properly reflecting changes. But to reflect the change in the UI, I have to refresh (F5) the (Chrome) browser.

CSHTML reference to the control is fairly straightforward:

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label style="white-space: nowrap;">Maximo Id's</label>
        <a id="btnAddMaximoEntry" onclick=window.allIsos.addMaximoEntry() href="#" title='Add Maximo' style='margin-left: 8px'><i class='fa fa-upload'></i></a>
        <div class="" id="divMaximoList">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The JS definition for the control is:

```
function addMaximoListView(isoId, outageId) {
  maximoListDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      read: { url: "/request/GetMaximoList", type: "GET", dataType: "json", cache: false },
      create: { url: "/request/AddMaximoEntry", type: "Post", dataType: "json", cache: false },
      destroy: { url: "/request/DeleteMaximoEntry", type: "POST", dataType: "json", cache: false },
      update: {},
      parameterMap: function (data, type) {
        if (type == "read") { return { IsoId: isoId, OutageId: outageId }; }
        if (type == "create") { return { MaximoId: data.MaximoId }; }
        if (type == "destroy") { return { id: data.Id }; }
      },
      sortable: true,
      pageable: true,
    },
    requestEnd: function (e) {
      console.log(e.type);
      console.log(e.response);
    },
    columns: [
      { field: "Id", Title: "Id", width: "0px" },
      { field: "MaximoId", Title: "MaximoId", width: "50px" },
      { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }
    ],
    autoSync: false,
    schema: {
      model: {
        id: "Id",
        fields: {
          Id: { editable: false },
          MaximoId: { editable: true, type: "string" },
        }
      },
    },
  });
  var getTemplate = ""
    + "<div>"
    + "    <a onclick=window.allIsos.deleteMaximo(#:Id#) href='\\#'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a>"
    + '#:MaximoId#</div>';
  var editTemplate = ""
    + "<div>"
    + "  <input type='text' data-bind='value: MaximoId' name='MaximoId' required='required' />"
    + "  <div>"
    + "    <a class='k-button k-update-button' href='\\#'><span class='k-icon k-i-check'></span></a>"
    + "    <a class='k-button k-cancel-button' href='\\#'><span class='k-icon k-i-cancel'></span></a>"
    + "  </div>"
    + "</div>";
  $("#divMaximoList").kendoListView({
    template: kendo.template(getTemplate),
    editTemplate: kendo.template(editTemplate),
    dataSource: maximoListDataSource,
    pageSize: 5,
    dataBound: function (e) {
      console.log("ListView is bound and ready to render.");
    }
  });
};
```

The JS definition to Add items to the list is:

```
var addMaximoEntry = function () {
  var listView = $("#divMaximoList").data("kendoListView");
  listView.add();
};
```

Debugging the local app with a fresh restart, here is the control exposing testing data from the API/Database:

[image]

I've clicked my ADD button, and before accepting the entry, please note the value entering as 'NotWorking' for my new MaximoId:

[image]

After accepting the input, note that the control has added a new entry but, it's a ghost of one of the original items:

[image]

However after refreshing the page (F5), note when the GET fires pulling from server-side TempData object, the actual 'NotWorking' item was properly received by the server, and that updated TempData object is passed to the UI (which includes the new entry):

[image]

The API method for the Create/Add is as follows - I'm returning to the UI, the JSON representation of the updated MaximoList object and using that updated object, am refreshing to TempData["MaximoList"]:

```
[HttpPost, Route("AddMaximoEntry")]
public ActionResult AddMaximoEntry(string MaximoId)
{
  var ignoreCase = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
  try
  {
    List<MaximoEntry> maximoList = TempData["MaximoList"] != null ? TempData["MaximoList"] as List<MaximoEntry> : new List<MaximoEntry>();

    var maximoId = MaximoId;// unnecessary variable, but used for testing against multiple method confgurations

    var maximoEntry = new MaximoEntry();
    maximoEntry.MaximoId = maximoId;

    if (maximoList.Where(s => s.MaximoId.Equals(maximoEntry.MaximoId, ignoreCase)).FirstOrDefault() == null)
      maximoList.Add(maximoEntry);

    TempData["MaximoList"] = maximoList as List<MaximoEntry>;
    return Json(maximoList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    var msg = $"Excepton: {ex.Message}. Inner Expection: {(ex.InnerException == null ? "N/A" : ex.InnerException.ToString())}";
    return new JsonResult
    {
      Data = new
      {
        id = 0,
        Success = false,
        Msg = "Something went wrong while adding to the Maximo List. Please contact system support!"
      }
    };
  }
}
```

And the API GET is as follow:

```
[HttpGet, Route("GetMaximoList")]
public ActionResult GetMaximoList(int IsoId, int OutageId)
{
  try
  {
    List<MaximoEntry> maximoList = ODataGetMaximoList(IsoId, OutageId);
    return Json(maximoList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    var msg = $"Excepton: {ex.Message}. Inner Expection: {(ex.InnerException == null ? "N/A" : ex.InnerException.ToString())}";
    return new JsonResult
    {
      Data = new
      {
        id = 0,
        Success = false,
        Msg = "Something went wrong while getting Maximo List. Please contact system support!"
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally, the API method for ADD(CREATE) passed back the entire List (JSON Array) of Maximo entries.

Solution is to pass back only the updated version of the **model** object initially passed to the ADD(CREATE) method, including the newly assigned "id" value. Newly created entries will have a negative index value which I'll later use at the DB level within a MERGE statement (ie negative values for the primary key shouldn't exist in the DB table) to sync the DB.

If not already clear, I'm using the TempData["MaximoList"] object to maintain the state of the Kendo ListView Control across API controllers. Saving the control state to the DB (leveraging the TempData object) will occur in a more generic controller method which doesn't manage state (adds/deletes/etc.) to the TempData object.

I've also reworked the DESTROY (Delete) components to remove deleted items from the (UI) list only on a successful API call, and have cleaned up the JS by removing a number of unnecessary sets to the control not required to reflect the state of TempData object.

My API Method for ADD method is now:

```
[HttpPost, Route("AddMaximoEntry")]
public JsonResult AddMaximoEntry(MaximoEntry model)
{
  var ignoreCase = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
  try
  {
    List<MaximoEntry> maximoList = TempData["MaximoList"] != null ? TempData["MaximoList"] as List<MaximoEntry> : new List<MaximoEntry>();

    var minId = maximoList.Where(w => w.id <= 0);
    model.id = minId.Count() == 0 ? -1 : minId.Select(s => s.id).Min() - 1;

    if (maximoList.Where(s => s.maximoId.Equals(model.maximoId, ignoreCase)).FirstOrDefault() == null)
      maximoList.Add(model);

    TempData["MaximoList"] = maximoList as List<MaximoEntry>;
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    var msg = $"Excepton: {ex.Message}. Inner Expection: {(ex.InnerException == null ? "N/A" : ex.InnerException.ToString())}";
    return new JsonResult
    {
      Data = new
      {
        Success = false,
        Msg = "Something went wrong while adding to the Maximo List. Please contact system support!"
      }
    };
  }
}
```

I've also updated my DELETE method, as an HTTPDELETE method, and returning a status indicator to alert the calling JS of operation outcome:

```
[HttpDelete, Route("DeleteMaximoEntry")]
public JsonResult DeleteMaximoEntry(int id)
{
  try
  {
    List<MaximoEntry> maximoList = TempData["MaximoList"] != null ? TempData["MaximoList"] as List<MaximoEntry> : new List<MaximoEntry>();

    var itemToRemove = maximoList.SingleOrDefault(r => r.id == id);
    if (itemToRemove != null)
      maximoList.Remove(itemToRemove);

    TempData["MaximoList"] = maximoList as List<MaximoEntry>;

    return Json(new { success = true, responseText = $"id {id} deleted from TempData object" });
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    var msg = $"Excepton: {ex.Message}. Inner Expection: {(ex.InnerException == null ? "N/A" : ex.InnerException.ToString())}";
    return new JsonResult
    {
      Data = new
      {
        Success = false,
        Msg = $"Something went wrong while deleteing Maximo Entry (id {id}). Please contact system support!"
      }
    };
  }
}
```

The JS control definition for SELECT (READ) and CREATE(Add) is:

```
function addMaximoListView(isoId, outageId) {
  maximoListDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      batch: false,//default is false
      read: { dataType: "json", cache: false, type: "GET", url: "/request/GetMaximoList" },
      create: { dataType: "json", cache: false, type: "POST", url: "/request/AddMaximoEntry" },
      parameterMap: function (data, type) {
        if (type == "read") { return { IsoId: isoId, OutageId: outageId }; }
        if (type == "create") { return { model: data }; }
      },
    },
    requestEnd: function (e) {
      console.log(e.type);
      console.log(e.response);
    },
    autoSync: false,
    serverFiltering: true,
    schema: {
      model: {
        id: "id",
        fields: {
          maximoId: { editable: true, type: "string" },
        }
      },
    },
  });
  var getTemplate = ""
    + "<div>"
    + "  <a onclick=window.allIsos.deleteMaximo(#:id#) href='\\#'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a>"
    + "  #:maximoId#"
    + "</div > ";
  var editTemplate = ""
    + "<div>"
    + "  <input type='text' data-bind='value: maximoId' name='MaximoId' required='required' />"
    + "  <div>"
    + "    <a class='k-button k-update-button' href='\\#'><span class='k-icon k-i-check'></span></a>"
    + "    <a class='k-button k-cancel-button' href='\\#'><span class='k-icon k-i-cancel'></span></a>"
    + "  </div>"
    + "</div>";

  $("#divMaximoList").kendoListView({
    template: kendo.template(getTemplate),
    editTemplate: kendo.template(editTemplate),
    dataSource: maximoListDataSource,
    dataBound: function (e) {
      console.log("ListView is bound and ready to render.");
    }
  });
};
```

For DESTROY (DELETE), I've added these JS methods (hope to embed these elements into the control defintion):

```
var deleteMaximo = function (id) {
  executeDeleteMaximo(id, "Are you sure you want to delete this Maximo entry?");
}

function executeDeleteMaximo(id, confirmMsg) {
  common.LoadingGif("#mainView", false);
  common.ConfirmDialog(true, confirmMsg,
    function (reason) {
      if (reason == "NO") {
        common.LoadingGif("#mainView", true);
        return false;
      }
      $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        data: { id: id },
        url: "/request/DeleteMaximoEntry",
        success: function (response) {
          var data = response;
          if (data.success) {
            var myDataSource = $("#divMaximoList").data().kendoListView.dataSource;
            var item = myDataSource.get(id);//need a check before attempting remove
            myDataSource.remove(item);

          }
          common.LoadingGif("#mainView", true);
          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          var e = errorThrown;
        }
      });
    });
}
```